# Cant assign CSS class in FormType Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, bundles

I installed bootstrap via bundle in Symfony2. But now I getting the some strange situation, when I append the class selcetor to form field of date type. In output I getting it with bootstrap-date class, and I cant change it. So where is the my problem? Thanks!
Here is the FormType code:

```
->add('startDate', 'date', [
            'label' => 'Start date',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'advanced_search_form',
            ],
 ])
```

Here is HTML:

Comment: Can we have the snippet of code where you inject the class and the final result (with Google toolbar for example) ?

Comment: @Hornth, look, I update post :)

Comment: In your browser, on your element, is your class applied but overrided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the twig template:

```
{{ form_widget(form.startDate, { 'attr': {'class': 'advanced_search_form'} }) }}
```